# Representation of ordinary differential operators in terms of a given regular operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, differential-operators

I'm trying to understand Lemma 3.2 from p. 355 of the paper [R. C. Carlson and K. R. Goodearl, *Commutants of Ordinary Differential Operators*, Journal of Differenial Equations **35** (1980), 339–365.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022039680900339)

> [image]

The authors define $B$ as a matrix coefficient with $C^\infty$ entries, $D$ is the ordinary derivative operator on $\bigoplus^k C^\infty(\mathscr J)$ for some open interval $\mathscr J$, and $L$ as the differential operator given below (from the previous page)

> [image]

$\textbf{Question}$:

I can't see how this is true that any differential operator can be written in this way. I'm trying to see it in the scalar case, i.e. where $A,B$ are $1\times 1$ matrices but I can't even construct non-trivial examples that can be written in that way. Moreover, I don't even understand what the proof is doing.

Comment: @epimorphic Nope! Thanks for your detailed response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing out the lower-order terms explicitly, we want to have $$C_m D^m = C_m A_n^{-r} D^s L^r + \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} E_j D^j$$ for some matrices $E_j$, so that $\sum_{j=0}^m C_j D^j$ can be written in a form known to satisfy the statement of the lemma: $$\sum_{j=0}^m C_j D^j = C_m A_n^{-r} D^s L^r + \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} (C_j + E_j) D^j.$$ To prove, it suffices to show that $D^s L^r$, when rearranged so that all of the $D$s (including the ones in $L$) are on the right, has the form $$D^s L^r = A_n^r D^m + \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} F_j D^j \tag{*}\label{com}$$ for some matrices $F_j$. This is done through the product rule $$DA = A' + AD,$$ where $A'$ is the component-wise derivative of $A$. Intuitively, the rule says that when trying to "commute" $D$ and $A$, we get a term where $D$ hits the $A$ and disappears, and another where $D$ actually manages to pass through. The only way to get a $D^m$ all the way to the right from $D^s L^r$, therefore, is to take the highest-order term $D^s (A_n D^n)^r$ and pass every $D$ to the right through the $A_n$; every other term will end up with a lower power of $D$. This results in $\eqref{com}$.

---

For a simple example, let $k=1$ as you said, and let $L = (x^2 + 1) D^2$ and $T = \sin(x) D^3$. Then $r = s = 1$. By the product rule, $DL = 2x D^2 + (x^2 + 1) D^3$, so $$T = \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2 + 1}DL - \frac{2x\sin(x)}{x^2 + 1} D^2 = \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2 + 1}DL - \frac{2x\sin(x)}{(x^2 + 1)^2} L.$$